# How to Use ConstrainLayout as Empty View

Tags: android, listview

I am using two child ConstraintLayouts inside another. The first child contains the empty view, and the second contains my listview and floating action button. When there is no data in the listview, the empty view rightly appears in its position. However, when there is data in listview, the listview shows up after a big empty area on the layout, as if the empty view still takes its space, though it is not shown.
This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <TextView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/tv_empty_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/list_is_empty"
            android:textSize="@dimen/large_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_empty_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_empty_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/list_is_empty"
            android:src="@drawable/emptybox" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content_area"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
            android:layout_height="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the layout on app launch with and without listview items:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you check my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your code .

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And default xml layout .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="584dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="584dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/list_is_empty"
        android:textSize="@dimen/large_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/list_is_empty"
        android:src="@drawable/emptybox"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_empty_view"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_area"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `content_area` is visible ,and `empty_view` is gone .

And in your code .

- If `ListView` 's data is not null ,you do not do any thing .
- If `ListView` 's data is null ,you should do this .

  ```
  // set empty_view visible
  ConstraintLayout empty_view = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
  empty_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  // set content_area gone
  ConstraintLayout content_area = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_area);
  content_area.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  ```